# Rounding months to the correct year

Tags: powerbi, dax, data-warehouse

I am creating an Age Dimension. 
Granularity is months, so i have started by creating a column called TotalMonths, between 1 - 1440, which equates to 120 years.

I now want to add a year column.
I thought totalMonths/12 would work, but on month 6, the year rounds up to 1.
The year should only round up after 12.

Is there a way to do this in dax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make a custom column in Power Query, then you can use [`Number.RoundDown`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/number-rounddown) function:

```
Year_M = Number.RoundDown([TotalMonths] / 12)
```

If you do it in DAX, then use [ROUNDDOWN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/rounddown-function-dax) function:

```
Year_DAX = ROUNDDOWN(Age[TotalMonths] / 12, 0)
```

[image]

If you want first `Year=1` to be for `TotalMonth=13` instead, then subtract 1 from `TotalMonth` in the above calculations:

```
Year_M = Number.RoundDown(([TotalMonths] - 1) / 12)
Year_DAX = ROUNDDOWN((Age[TotalMonths] - 1) / 12, 0)
```

[image]